# Unix shell scripting - multiple file concatenate

Tags: shell, unix

consider the scenario-

file1:

```
mike;john;552
mike;mike;555
john;mike;121
```

file2:

```
aks;raj;425
man;joe;895
mike;john;552
```

Assuming file1 and file2 contain the above two sets of data. I would like to put the data from these two files into another file , where the data is uniq ( meaning: file1 and file2 contain common data `mike;john;552`, but when conbining files i do not want to have duplicates.

I used the command:

```
cat file1 file2 | sort -u > file3
```

but this gave me only the common line ie, the duplicate into file3.

Also tried

```
cat file1 file2 | uniq > file3
```

Didnt yield required result.

Expected output: 
file3:

```
mike;john;552
mike;mike;555
john;mike;121
aks;raj;425
man;joe;895
```

Note: the data in file3 can be in any order.

Please help on this.

Comment: The `cat file1 file2 | sort -u` works well for me: all lines from file1 and file2 merged and duplicate lines are printed only once.

Comment: CNR. These tools work precisely in accordance with the described desired behavior.

Comment: Okay worked now, guess had the white space issue.Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

Your first command works for me and gives the expected output:

```
$ cat -v file1
mike;john;552
mike;mike;555
john;mike;121

$ cat -v file2
aks;raj;425
man;joe;895
mike;john;552

$ cat file1 file2 | sort -u > file3
$ cat file3
aks;raj;425
john;mike;121
man;joe;895
mike;john;552
mike;mike;555
```

If this doesn't happen for you, use `cat -vE` to find out why. Here are two examples:

```
$ cat file1 file2 | sort -u
foo
foo   

$ cat file1 file2 | sort -u | cat -vE
foo$
foo   $
```

In this case, it looks like you get duplicates, but the lines are actually different because of **trailing whitespace**.

```
$ cat file1 file2 | sort -u 
foo
foo
$ cat file1 file2 | sort -u | cat -vE
foo$
foo^M$
```

In this case, it also looks like you get duplicates, but one file has **carriage returns** because it was saved in DOS/Windows mode instead of Unix mode.